# Javascript validation script

Tags: javascript, validation

I am struggling to understand where there is a mistake.
After many tries, I tend to think that it's something about overalcheck()...
The append, clearelement and writeto are the additional mini functions and they are totally fine.
So, this script checks the form, and if everything is ok, opens a new page. However, if a field is empty or has a wrong type, it shows the relative error message (or a list of error messages).
I made a lot of variations, sometimes it opens without a completed form (like the code below), sometimes it shows the error message for 1 field only and then, and even if you complete all fields, it still doesnt open a new page.
I would appreciate your help.

```
 <script>

    function overallcheck ()
    {
        if(!checkname() || !checkemail() || !checkjob())
        {
            writeTo("problemArea","Error messages area");

            if(!checkname())
                writeTo("problemArea","Please insert a valid name");
            if(!checkemail())
                writeTo("problemArea","Please insert a valid email");
            if(!checkjob())
                writeTo("problemArea","Please insert your job");
            return false;                   
        }
        return true;
    }

    function checkname()
    {
        clearElement("problemArea");
        var fullname = document.forms['form'].fullname.value;
        if (fullname.length == 0 || !isNaN(fullname)) 
            return false;
    }

    function checkemail()
    {
        clearElement("problemArea");
        var mail = document.forms['form'].Email.value;
        if (mail == '' || mail.indexOf('@') == -1 || mail.indexOf('.') == -1) 
            return false;
    }

    function checkjob()
    {
        clearElement("problemArea");
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if (document.forms['form'].job[i].checked) {return true;}
        }
        return false;
    }

    </script>

    <body>
      <form onsubmit="return overallcheck();" action="res.html" id=form target="_blank" method="GET">
<table>

                <tr>
                    <td><b><p>blabla?</p></b> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="fullname"  size="20" placeholder="Enter a valid name"/> </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><b><p> E-mail: </p></b></td> 
                    <td><input type="email" name="email" maxlength="15" size = "20" placeholder="Enter a valid email address"/> </td>
                </tr>

<tr>
<p><td><b><p>bla?</td></p>
                <td>1<input type="radio" name="job" value="gov" /><br/>
                2<input type="radio" name="job" value="pri" /><br/><div id="problemArea"> </div>
                3<input type="radio" name="job" value="unem" /><br/>
                                4<input type="radio" name="job" value="other" /><br/>

</td></tr>
</table>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" onclick="" >clickme</button>

        </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: All your functions except *checkjob* return *false* or *undefined*, so expressions like `!checkname()` resolve to *true* either way. Oh, and `!isNaN(fullname)` doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: also `checkname` != `Checkname`

Comment: I'll also be "that guy" and point out you shouldn't rely on client-side form validation in general.. hopefully this is just some pre-validation to cut down on server requests, and you're doing real validation on your server, right? right?

Comment: you should share your form.

Answer (score 0):

Track each error type with it's own div.  Wrap overallcheck in a try catch to and alert errors. This helped find the "Email" error.

```js
function writeTo(id, msg) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
}

function clearElement(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
}

function overallcheck() {
  try {
    if (!checkname() || !checkemail() || !checkjob()) {


      if (!checkname())
        writeTo("problem_fullname", "Please insert a valid name");
      if (!checkemail())
        writeTo("problem_email", "Please insert a valid email");
      if (!checkjob())
        writeTo("problem_blah", "Please insert your job");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
}

function checkname() {
  clearElement("problem_fullname");
  var fullname = document.forms['form'].fullname.value;
  if (fullname.length == 0 || !isNaN(fullname)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function checkemail() {
  clearElement("problem_email");
  var mail = document.forms['form'].email.value; //Email.value;
  if (mail == '' || mail.indexOf('@') == -1 || mail.indexOf('.') == -1) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function checkjob() {
  clearElement("problem_blah");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (document.forms['form'].job[i].checked) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
td {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.problem {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return overallcheck();" action="res.html" id=form target="_blank" method="GET">
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td><b><p>blabla?</p></b> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" size="20" placeholder="Enter a valid name" />
        <div id="problem_fullname" class="problem"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><b><p> E-mail: </p></b>
      </td>
      <td>

        <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="15" size="20" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />
        <div id="problem_email" class="problem"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <p>
        <td><b><p>bla?</td></p>
                <td>
                1<input type="radio" name="job" value="gov" /><br/>
                2<input type="radio" name="job" value="pri" /><br/>
                3<input type="radio" name="job" value="unem" /><br/>
                4<input type="radio" name="job" value="other" /><br/>
                <div id="problem_blah" class="problem"> </div>

</td></tr>
</table>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" onclick="" >clickme</button>

        </form>
```